# Generating welcome messages

Tags: facebook

Apps like Facebook display a welcome message at the top of the news feed contextually relevant at the time of day

- Good morning John
- Hi John
- Nice afternoon John
- Good day John

Are these simply lists of phrases picked out at random based on the time of day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook gets all sorts of data from you.The time of day surely decides the gist of the greeting, but Facebook also has information about where you are from, where you live, and even (though I am not sure they really bother to collect and analyze this data, though they may) lots of examples of the way you and the people on your friends list speak. If you start getting greetings that are colloquialisms of where you from, then you know how well Facebook's algorithms know you!
Lots of programs use your data to give you a more human like experience. Its something to be aware of when using, and making, software.

Answer (score 0):

They are based on the time you Local time...